# Scroll of window doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I have some div and I want that, when I click on one of them, it automatic scroll to the top of the current window. 
So, I calculated the current position (relative to the window), I calculated the height of the window, and I animated scroll to the position given by the difference between the previous numbers. But it doesn't scroll. Why?

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/8dhhbk9r/

JS code:

```
        $('.post').each(function() {
        var post = $(this);
        post.text( post.position().top - $(window).scrollTop() );
        post.click(function() {
        var where = post.position().top - $(window).scrollTop();
        var h = $(window).height();
        var scrollTo = h - where;
        post.animate({
        scrollTop: scrollTo
     }, 800);
         });
    });
```

Comment: do you want the clicked div to scroll to the top of window?

Comment: Yes, when I click on one '.post' the page has to scroll while the clicked element is on the top of the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".post").on("click", function(){
   $("body, html").animate({'scrollTop': $(this).offset().top}, 1000 );
});//click
```